# SQL Server: Execute nvarchar SQL statement and parametrize results without OUTPUT parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to execute a SQL statement stored in nvarchar or ntext and parameterize the results of the executed SQL statement without using sp_executesql? E.g.

```
@SQL = 'SELECT name FROM db.dbo.employees WHERE income > 50000'
```

In this case, in a stored procedure, could I extract name without having to modify the query so I can use sp_executesql with an OUTPUT parameter defined for name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What in the world is preventing you from using SP_EXECUTESQL? Is this a strip from Dilbert?

Anyway, if you used an output parameter with that specific query, it'll most likely return a single (random) value from all employees whose income exceed 50,000.  Here's an example showing how to return an entire result to the caller of a dynamic SQL statement.

The key here is **INSERT.. EXEC**

```
create table dbo.employees (
  name varchar(10),
  income int);
insert employees values
 ('john', 10000),
 ('joe' , 20000),
 ('joey', 40000),
 ('bob' , 70000),
 ('tim' , 100000);

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) =
    'SELECT name FROM dbo.employees WHERE income > 50000';

declare @names table (name varchar(20));
insert @names
EXEC (@SQL);
select * from @names;
```

Comment: oh drat my contrived example wasn't very good. Sorry about that. I like your solution as it allows for a cursor to be declared and then I am free to fetch each name. nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example how you can use completely dynamic SQL in SQL server with parameterize SQL Query.

```
SET @Sql = N'UPDATE ' + @tablen + ' SET LOSS_SCORE=0.00, EARNED_SCORE=0.00  WHERE SECTIONSUBTYPE_CODE!=''NW'' AND 
BATCH_IDENTITY ='''+@BATCH_IDENTIFIER+''' AND PACK_NO IN (SELECT PACK_NO FROM ' + @tablen + ' WHERE 
BATCH_IDENTITY =''' +@BATCH_IDENTIFIER+''' AND ECTIONSUBTYPE_CODE=''NW'' AND LOSS_SCORE=100.00)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

I used in my project and it's working fine. Hope it will help you as well.